# ArgumentNullException message without parameter name

Tags: c#, exception, argumentexception, argumentnullexception

I am throwing ArgumentNullException in part of my code in C#. I want to catch and display the error message of my exception. But without the parameter name. I want to pass the parameter name to the exception constructor.

```
throw new ArgumentNullException("myParameter", errorMessageStringVariable);
```

If I call `error.Message` I get something like

errorMessageStringVariable 
parameter name: myParameter

I want to display only the errorMessageStringVariable. Is it possible using ArgumentNullException, without some kind of formating on the error.Message?

Comment: Are you throwing any other exception that inherits from `ArgumentException`?

Comment: None that I know of. But to be honest, the throwing of exception and try block are several levels apart and I don't dare to say that some other code called in between doesn't throw such exception. The code that I work on is really obscure. I'm not familiar with every possible execution path that takes place within the try block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to construct the exception without the name, use:

```
new ArgumentNullException(null, errorMessageStringVariable)
```

But if you want to present an `ArgumentNullException` where the `paramName` is set, the answer seems to be no. You have to use string manipulation on the `Message` property.

You could create a new class that derives from `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: Thank you. That's all that I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

If you call:

```
new ArgumentNullException(null, errorMessageStringVariable)
```

The exception message will be:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: errorMessageStringVariable

If you instead use:

```
new ArgumentNullException(string.Empty, errorMessageStringVariable)
```

you will only get the error message.

Comment: Your first claim is simply incorrect. [Try it online (C# code is encoded in URL).](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEETv@Yqhpxa0P1A8iHizRVDwHOJSAulGuttakX57rEUvA/NmeE62TlxKg3hucXmJUlcZI2rVO7hgRXA2bwP80Bj9HbX1nBcL/A7AaHtYJuzA9MS@b4eOWJshhOPk6KE@cs5L2yC70qTQf2RFtQoOkSUGKm@9Vzp5pnzRlTWJ2JbWz2zmlD4) In my opinion the use of an empty string is dubious.

Comment: Also note that `(new ArgumentNullException()).ParamName` is a null reference, not an empty string. That shows that the `ParamName` property is meant to be `null` (not `""`) when the parameter name is omitted.